# Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:16.0.8

Tags: android, firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging

I meet this error message when trying to build apk by using "ionic cordova build android".

Error Message:

> BUILD FAILED in 9s
>   /platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
>     Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:16.0.8.
>     Required by:
>        project :app

My "ionic info":

> Ionic:
>
> ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.12.0
>   (/home/jiahao/opt/node-v10.16.3-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/ionic)
>   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.10
>   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.10    @angular-devkit/schematics 
>   : 7.3.10    @angular/cli                  : 7.3.10
>   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.5.1
>
> Cordova:
>
> cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.1-nightly.2019.3.20.f1a8fe80
>   (cordova-lib@9.0.1-nightly.2019.3.20.f0acd552)    Cordova Platforms
>   : android 8.1.0    Cordova Plugins       :
>   cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
>   4.1.3, (and 15 other plugins)
>
> System:
>
> Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
>   (/home/user/Android/sdk-tools-linux-4333796)    NodeJS            :
>   v10.16.3 (/home/user/opt/node-v10.16.3-linux-x64/bin/node)    npm
>   : 6.9.0    OS                : Linux 5.3

Gradle Version: 6.0

I tried:
 1. Change gradle version to 4.10.2 (now change back to 6.0).
 2. Change version of com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0 to 4.0.2 in main build.gradle file.

I already stuck in this problem long time already... Please help me. Very very thanks.
If want to check any other version or something else please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem already.
By change the "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging" version from 16.0.8 to 17.0.+ at project.properties file.

Comment: same problem, but I haven't `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging` in roject.properties. Should I add this?